# Liferay portlet + Single page html, css, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, liferay, web-deployment

I have a static Single Page - html, css and javascript files. I have tested by deploying it into apache-tomcat and it works.
I would like to convert this html, css and javascript as **Porlet**.

So far, I have done the followings,

1. Created the liferay - maven project (Through eclipse) [I have build and tested, this porlet is working when i deploy as war in LifeRay)
2. In liferays maven project: ..src/main/webapp/ folder i have created a new folder called myapp
3. Have pasted all the html, css, javascripts inside the myapp folder
4. In the view.jsp file, i have included the myapp/index.html file.
   Build the war and deployed into liferay.

Here, it is successfully picking the myapp/index.html in liferay porlet. However, it is not picking any resources inside the index.html (css, javascript).

Here, how can i make this porlet up and working correctly. Please assist. *Kindly note that, i have tested this static page in independent tomcat server, it works fine. So that means, all the resource path that I have given is correct in index.html*

Comment: I'm assuming that your html page has '<head>' and '<body>' sections?

Comment: Check the developper console of your browser. This should give you hints about wrong paths of the css, js files.